# Moving average for all unique records in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a table structure as below

SQL> desc trx_mf_amfi_navs ;

```
Name                   Type          Nullable Default Comments 
---------------------- ------------- -------- ------- -------- 
SCHEME_CODE            NUMBER                                  
ISIN_DIV_PAYOUT_GROWTH VARCHAR2(100) Y                         
ISIN_DIV_REINVESTMENT  VARCHAR2(100) Y                         
SCHEME_NAME            VARCHAR2(200) Y                         
NET_ASSET_VALUE        NUMBER        Y                         
NAV_DATE               DATE
```

Below are the records for different mutual funds scheme and have displayed only 2 Scheme Code details
[image]

I wrote a query as below

```
Select t1.scheme_code,
       t1.scheme_name,
       t1.net_asset_value,
       round(avg(t1.net_asset_value)
             over(partition by t1.scheme_code order by t1.scheme_code
                  rows between 3 preceding and current row),
             4) as "3Day_SMA"
  from trx_mf_amfi_navs t1
 where t1.scheme_code in ('118834', '118825')
   and t1.nav_date >= '01-FEB-2022'
```

Result as below from query
[image]

I would like to have the output for all schemes with moving average for last nav_date for that scheme_code

```
Scheme_Code,Scheme_Name, NET_ASSET_VALUE,max(nav_date),3day_SMA

118825  Mirae Asset Large Cap Fund - Direct Plan - Growth   81.56   28-FEB-2022 81.1173
118834  Mirae Asset Emerging Bluechip Fund - Direct Plan - Growth   100.84  28-FEB-2022 99.7675
```

Your help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood u right u are just trying to summarize your existing table with 3day_SMA to a table that contains only last day rows grouped by scheme_code. If that s what u are looking for then this should solve your problem:

```
 with
test1 as(
         Select t1.scheme_code,
                t1.scheme_name,
                t1.net_asset_value,
                t1.nav_date,
                round(avg(t1.net_asset_value)
                      over(partition by t1.scheme_code order by t1.scheme_code
                           rows between 3 preceding and current row),
                           4) as "3Day_SMA"
        from trx_mf_amfi_navs t1
        where t1.scheme_code in ('118834', '118825')
        and t1.nav_date >= '01-FEB-2022'
        )
        select * from test1 where (scheme_code,nav_date) in
        (select scheme_code,max(nav_date) from test1 group by scheme_code)
```

Or with join on:

```
 Select t1.scheme_code,
        t1.scheme_name,
        t1.net_asset_value,
        t2.max_date,
        t1."3Day_SMA"
        from 
        (select scheme_code,scheme_name, net_asset_value,nav_date, round(avg(net_asset_value)
        over(partition by scheme_code order by scheme_code
        rows between 3 preceding and current row),4) as "3Day_SMA" from trx_mf_amfi_navs) t1,
        (select scheme_code,max(nav_date) max_date from trx_mf_amfi_navs group by scheme_code) t2
        where
        t1.scheme_code=t2.scheme_code
        and t1.scheme_code in ('118834', '118825')
        and t1.nav_date >= '01-FEB-2022'
        and t1.nav_date=t2.max_date
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I found what i wanted and knew my mistake, My table has millions of records, Is there a way it can be done using a join ?

Comment: I edited the post, it may be little bit faster with join but probably the best solution is to make a view (and then query max(date) on the view) and create index on the table if it doesn t have PK.

Comment: You are welcome, can you just mark the question as solved if the code i posted is your solution

Comment: Results in Join Query display displays the same value in Net_Asset_value & 3day_SMA where as IN query shows perfect results

Comment: Sorry didn t see that, I updated the code now it works

Comment: Results is proper from Join Query, Thanks, How do i mark the question as close?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. More info on: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)